# How to write different long data into file in R?

Tags: r

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [R: Print list to a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3044794/r-print-list-to-a-text-file)

ther are two vectors,x1,x2

```
x1<-1:3
x2<-1:6
```

i want to write the two vectors into a file named `test` in the following format

```
1 2 3
1 2 3 4 5 6
```

(one vector in one line in the file)

```
write(file="c:/test",x1)  
write(file="c:/test",x2,append=TRUE,nlines=6)
```

is there a  simple way to do ?

Comment: Just use `rbind`, guys!  Keep it simple.

Answer (score 4):

An easier way - both in terms of writing and reading the data - is to use `save` and `load`:

```
##Save both objects to the file
##BTW, you should always use a file extension
save(x1, x2, file="c:/test.RData")

##Loads both objects into your workspace
load("c:/test.RData")
```

Comment: +1, in addition to easier it is also more robust, and in case floats, no loss of precision. And, `save` can handle any R object.

Answer (score 3):

This is a way to write all objects to the same file with one command:

```
lapply(list(x1, x2), function(x) write(x, "c:/test", length(x), TRUE))
```

Comment: While a one-liner is convenient, beware that the file is opened and closed twice so this won't scale well. You'll prefer to write to a file connection (see `?file`) when this gets too slow.

Answer (score 1):

You could also `paste` the numbers into a character vector, and use `writeLines` to dump them to a file connection.

```
dat = list(vec1, vec2)
dat_write = paste(dat, collapse = " ")
con = file("c:\test", "w")
writeLines(dat_write, con)
close(con)
```

Comment: +1 for opening a file connection which can make a big difference. However I don't think the output is what the OP is expecting, see what `as.character(dat)` does. You could use `invisible(lapply(dat, cat, "\n", file = con))` instead.