# R: Export and import a list to .txt file

Tags: r, list, export-to-csv

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3044794/r-print-list-to-a-text-file) suggests a way to write a list to a file.

```
lapply(mylist, write, "test.txt", append=TRUE, ncolumns=1000)
```

The issue with this technic is that part of the information of the list (the structure into subparts and the names of the subparts) disappear and it is therefore very complicated (or impossible if we lost the extra information) to recreate the original list from the file.

**What is the best solution to export and import (without causing any modification, including the names) a list?**

Comment: `dput` `dump` or `save` will all write out R objects to an external file. `save` will give a binary format while the other two text representations.

Comment: why not use `?saveRDS` or something?

Comment: If you wanted exactly what you see on console output, then:  `cat(capture.output(print(my.list), file="test.txt")` although I think the dput strategy will be superior since it can be `source()`-ed

Comment: @thelatemail I didn't know these functions and they were exactly what I needed. I ended up using `dput` and `dget`. Can you convert your comment into an answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save your list using these commands (given that there are no element names containing a dot)

```
l1 <- list(a = 1, b = list(c = 1, d = 2))
vectorElements <- unlist(l1)
vectorPaths <- names(vectorElements)
vectorRows <- paste(vectorPaths, vectorElements)
write.table(vectorRows, "vectorRows.txt", row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE)
```

Each line of the file corresponds to an element in this format

```
node1.node2.node3 leaf
```

Then, you'll be able to re-build the list structure.

Comment: This won't work reliably: list names can have . `.` in them, and so you can't guarantee that re-building the structure will result in the same list. In fact, I think they can have basically any character in them, e.g. `list('a:2^ 3' = 42)` works.

Comment: And how would you import the list back in from the .txt?

Answer (score 0):

You could just use the yaml library:

```
R> library(yaml)
R> l1 <- list('1'=2, se7en=list('som:eth|ng~horr1ßl€'=42))
R> l1
$`1`
[1] 2

$se7en
$se7en$`som:eth|ng~horr1ßl€`
[1] 42
R> cat(as.yaml(l1), file='blah.txt')
R> l2 <- yaml.load_file('blah.txt')
R> l2
$`1`
[1] 2

$se7en
$se7en$`som:eth|ng~horr1ßl€`
[1] 42
```

Answer (score 0):

I export lists into YAML format with [CPAN YAML package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/yaml/index.html)

```
l <- list(a="1", b=1, c=list(a="1", b=1))
yaml::write_yaml(l, "list.yaml")
```

Bonus of YAML that it's a human readable text format so it's easy to read or share

```
$ cat list.yaml
a: '1'
b: 1.0
c:
  a: '1'
  b: 1.0
```