# How to get a frequency table of all columns of complete data frame in R?

Tags: r

I want to create a frequency table from a data frame and save it in excel. Using `table()` function i can only create frequency of a particular column. But I want to create frequency table for all the columns altogether, and for each column the levels or type of variables may differ too. Like kind of summary of a data frame but there will not be mean or other measures, only frequencies.
I was trying something like this

```
 for(i in 1:230){
 rm(tb)
 tb<-data.frame(table(mydata[i]))
 tb2<-cbind(tb2,tb)
 }
```

But it's showing the following Error

> Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) :    arguments imply
>   differing number of rows: 15, 12

In place of `cbind()` I also used `data.frame()` but the Error didn't changed.

Comment: what about `lapply(mydata,table)`?

Comment: The error means that tb2 contains 15 rows and tb contains 12 rows.

Comment: I just tried `lapply(mydata,table)` while trying to save it in a csv file using write.csv, it produces an Error `Error in data.frame(s_id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 24066, 27558, 17779, 18466, 3, 15, 5, 12, 13, 10, 4, 9, 7, 2, 21, 20, 51, 14, 23, 24, 31, 6, 26, 8, 55, 576, 1027, 2459, 363, 1973, 765`. Same error while I was trying to use `data.frame()` as well over the result too.

Comment: As you say, levels of variables might differ. How do you expect to create a data frame with frequencies for all variables? You might be able to do something like min, max, mean, frequency as all your columns will produce 3 values no matter what.

Answer (score 8):

You are getting an error because you are trying to combine the data frames that have different dimensions. From what I understand, your problem is two-fold: (1) you want to get the frequency distribution of each column regardless of type; and, (2) you want to save all of the results in a single Excel sheet.

For the first problem, you can use the `mapply()` function.

```
set.seed(1)

dat <- data.frame(
  x = sample(LETTERS[1:5], 15, replace = TRUE),
  y = rbinom(5, 15, prob = 0.4)
)

mylist <- mapply(table, dat); mylist

# $x
# 
# A B C D E 
# 2 5 1 4 3 
# 
# $y
# 
# 5  6  7 11 
# 3  3  6  3
```

You can also use `purrr::map()`.

```
library(purrr)
dat %>% map(table)
```

The second problem has several solutions in this question: [Export a list into a CSV or TXT file in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27594541/export-a-list-into-a-csv-or-txt-file-in-r). In particular, LyzandeR's answer will enable you to do just what you intended. If you prefer to save the outputs in separate files, you can do:

```
mapply(write.csv, mylist, file=paste0(names(mylist), '.csv'))
```

Answer (score 6):

Maybe an rbind solution is better as it allows you to handle variables with different levels:

```
dt = data.frame(x = c("A","A","B","C"),
                y = c(1,1,2,1))

dt

#   x y
# 1 A 1
# 2 A 1
# 3 B 2
# 4 C 1

dt_res = data.frame()

for (i in 1:ncol(dt)){

dt_temp = data.frame(t(table(dt[,i])))
dt_temp$Var1 = names(dt)[i]

dt_res = rbind(dt_res, dt_temp)

}

names(dt_res) = c("Variable","Levels","Freq")

dt_res

#   Variable Levels Freq
# 1        x      A    2
# 2        x      B    1
# 3        x      C    1
# 4        y      1    3
# 5        y      2    1
```

And an alternative (probably faster) process using apply:

```
dt = data.frame(x = c("A","A","B","C"),
                y = c(1,1,2,1))

dt

ff = function(x){

  y = data.frame(t(table(x)))
  y$Var1 = NULL
  names(y) = c("Levels","Freq")
  return(y)
}

dd = do.call(rbind, apply(dt, 2, ff)) 

dd

#     Levels Freq
# x.1      A    2
# x.2      B    1
# x.3      C    1
# y.1      1    3
# y.2      2    1


# extract variable names from row names
dd$Variable = sapply(row.names(dd), function(x) unlist(strsplit(x,"[.]"))[1])

dd

#     Levels Freq Variable
# x.1      A    2        x
# x.2      B    1        x
# x.3      C    1        x
# y.1      1    3        y
# y.2      2    1        y
```

Answer (score 2):

## Edit (2021-03-29): `tidyverse` Principles

Here is some updated code that utilizes `tidyverse`, specifically functions from `dplyr`, `tibble`, and `purrr`. The code is a bit more readable and easier to carry out as well. Example data set is provided.

```
tibble(
    a = rep(c(1:3), 2),
    b = factor(rep(c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar"), 2)),
    c = factor(rep(LETTERS[1:3], 2))
    ) -> 
    dat

dat #print df

# A tibble: 6 x 3
    a    b    c    
  <int> <fct> <fct>
1     1 Jan   A    
2     2 Feb   B    
3     3 Mar   C    
4     1 Jan   A    
5     2 Feb   B    
6     3 Mar   C
```

Get counts and proportions across columns.

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
#library(tidyverse) #to load assortment of pkgs

#output tables - I like to use parentheses & specifying my funs
purrr::map(
    dat, function(.x) {
        count(tibble(x = .x), x) %>% 
            mutate(pct = (n / sum(n) * 100)) 
        })

#here is the same code but more concise (tidy eval)
purrr::map(dat, ~ count(tibble(x = .x), x) %>% 
               mutate(pct = (n / sum(n) * 100)))

$a
# A tibble: 6 x 3
      x     n   pct
  <int> <int> <dbl>
1     1     1  16.7
2     2     1  16.7
3     3     1  16.7
4     4     1  16.7
5     5     1  16.7
6     6     1  16.7

$b
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  x         n   pct
  <fct> <int> <dbl>
1 Feb       2  33.3
2 Jan       2  33.3
3 Mar       2  33.3

$c
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  x         n   pct
  <fct> <int> <dbl>
1 A         3    50
2 B         3    50
```

---

## Old code...

The `table()` function returns a "table" object, which is nigh impossible to manipulate using R in my experience. I tend to just write my own function to circumvent this issue. Let's first create a data frame with some categorical variables/features (wide formatted data).

We can use `lapply()` in conjunction with the `table()` function found in base R to create a list of frequency counts for each feature.

```
freqList = lapply(select_if(dat, is.factor), 
              function(x) {
                  df = data.frame(table(x))
                  names(df) = c("x", "y")
                  
                  return(df) 
                    }
                )
```

This approach allows each list object to be easily indexed and further manipulated if necessary, which can be really handy with data frames containing a lot of features. Use `print(freqList)` to view all of the frequency tables.

Comment: If proportion tables (i.e., percent of total observations) is the goal for multiple columns then try my post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32220202/how-to-get-a-frequency-table-of-all-columns-of-complete-data-frame-in-r/59169446#59169446).