# How to make frequency table for all categorical variables in a dataframe?

Tags: r

I tried to apply for loop to get count for each column in the dataframe. I created a freq names dataframe which only contains categorical variables.

```
 n <- names(freq)
for(var in n){
  count(freq,var)
}
```

I am getting the following **error**:

> Error in grouped_df_impl(data, unname(vars), drop) :    Column `var`
>   is unknown

Comment: Please give a [mcve]. See [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/4996248) for what this would mean in R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `var` as a character string, when `dplyr::count` needs a variable. to get the variable, use `get`.
In this example, the dataframe `freq` will be the built int dataset `iris`.

```
freq <- iris

n <- names(freq)
n <- n[sapply(n, function(var) is.factor(freq[[var]]))]

for(var in n){
  cnt <- dplyr::count(freq, get(var))
  print(cnt)
}
## A tibble: 3 x 2
#  `get(var)`     n
#  <fct>      <int>
#1 setosa        50
#2 versicolor    50
#3 virginica     50
```

Answer (score 0):

The `table` function in base R is really helpful in creating counts of categorical variables; however, the output is a specific table object - thus it is not recognized by almost any subsequent functions within R that would prove useful (`ggplot`, `kable`, etc.).

Here's a function that creates a list comprising the count of each level within the factors and converts them to data frames.

```
#df should be a data structure containing the factors of interest
freqList = lapply(df, 
              function(x) {

                  my_lst = data.frame(table(x))
                  names(my_lst) = c("level", "n")

                  return(my_lst) 
                    }
                )
freqList
```

Calling `freqList` will print the full list. Each column/variable will be its own data frame object.

Comment: This is basically the same as my post that can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59169446/12224152)