# How to save a dataframe with list to csv file in R

Tags: r, list, csv, arraylist, dataframe

I don't know if is possible...

I would save the file to import it in others future sessions.

I wanna save this data.frame in a csv file (it's a list of list containing vectors):

```
> operacions<-list(list(Nom="Victor",Bolis= c("Negro","azul","verde")),list(Nom="Dani",Lapices=c(1:4)))
> operacions
[[1]]
[[1]]$Nom
[1] "Victor"

[[1]]$Bolis
[1] "Negro" "azul"  "verde"


[[2]]
[[2]]$Nom
[1] "Dani"

[[2]]$Lapices
[1] 1 2 3 4
```

But it give me an error:

```
> write.csv2(operacions, "file.csv",row.names = FALSE)
Error in data.frame(list(Nom = "Victor", Bolis = c("Negro", "azul", "verde" : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 3, 4
```

Comment: This is not a data frame, this is a list of lists. The problem here is that the elements have differing lengths.. `rapply(operacions, length)` returns `1 3 1 4`. This is a problem, because `.csv` requires fixed lengths. What would the expected format of the output be here?

Comment: This may answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27594769/5805670

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it's not a data.frame , and more specifically cannot be coerced to one with as.data.frame which is where that message came from, you need to think of a different method of saving the data. Probably this simplest would be with `dput`, which writes an ASCII representation of the list structure:

```
dput(operacions, file="out.txt")
```

To bring it back into R:

```
new <- source("out.txt")
```

Another method would be to convert to JSON format, which would also preserve the key-value information rather than just writing the values:

```
library(jsonlite)
 toJSON(new)
# value---------
{"value":[{"Nom":["Victor"],"Bolis":["Negro","azul","verde"]},{"Nom":["Dani"],"Lapices":[1,2,3,4]}],"visible":[true]}
```

You can use the cat function to direct this to a text file:

```
cat( toJSON(new), file="test.3.txt")
```

Answer (score 0):

R Data frames and R lists are potentially incompatible...

A list is, essentially a vector where each element can be of a different type and length of elements. Meanwhile, a Data frame can be thought of a uniform spreadsheet where each column can store a different type of data, or nonnested lists ***where each element is of the same length***. This last point is important as lists can have unequal lengths, whilst a Data frames do not.

Thus, it may be easier to save the list as an RDS file using [saveRDS()](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/base/saverds)

```
dataDir <- "."
saveRDS( operacions, file.path(dataDir, "files"))
operacions2 <- readRDS(file.path(dataDir, "files"))
```

this will save it as an R-Object, and similarly, restore the R object later.

If you do want to convert to a data frame you can first convert to a nested data frame, and then fill in the blanks in the data frame. Thus...

```
require(data.table)
require(plyr)


operacions<-list(list(Nom="Victor",Bolis= c("Negro","azul","verde")),list(Nom="Dani",Lapices=c(1:4)))
str(operacions)
operacionsdf <- lapply(operacions, data.frame, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
str(operacionsdf)

operacionsdf2 <- rbind.fill(operacionsdf)
str(operacionsdf2)
write.csv2(operacionsdf2, "file.csv",row.names = FALSE)
operacionsdf3 <- read.csv2("file.csv")
str(operacionsdf3)
```

output:

```
> require(data.table)
> require(plyr)
> operacions<-list(list(Nom="Victor",Bolis= c("Negro","azul","verde")),list(Nom="Dani",Lapices=c(1:4)))
> str(operacions)
List of 2
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ Nom  : chr "Victor"
  ..$ Bolis: chr [1:3] "Negro" "azul" "verde"
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ Nom    : chr "Dani"
  ..$ Lapices: int [1:4] 1 2 3 4
> operacionsdf <- lapply(operacions, data.frame, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
> str(operacionsdf)
List of 2
 $ :'data.frame':   3 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ Nom  : chr [1:3] "Victor" "Victor" "Victor"
  ..$ Bolis: chr [1:3] "Negro" "azul" "verde"
 $ :'data.frame':   4 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ Nom    : chr [1:4] "Dani" "Dani" "Dani" "Dani"
  ..$ Lapices: int [1:4] 1 2 3 4
> operacionsdf2 <- rbind.fill(operacionsdf)
> str(operacionsdf2)
'data.frame':   7 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ Nom    : chr  "Victor" "Victor" "Victor" "Dani" ...
 $ Bolis  : chr  "Negro" "azul" "verde" NA ...
 $ Lapices: int  NA NA NA 1 2 3 4
> write.csv2(operacionsdf2, "file.csv",row.names = FALSE)
> operacionsdf3 <- read.csv2("file.csv")
> str(operacionsdf3)
'data.frame':   7 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ Nom    : Factor w/ 2 levels "Dani","Victor": 2 2 2 1 1 1 1
 $ Bolis  : Factor w/ 3 levels "azul","Negro",..: 2 1 3 NA NA NA NA
 $ Lapices: int  NA NA NA 1 2 3 4
```