# How to write each element in a list to different row in R?

Tags: r, csv

I have a list, like this:

```
x <- 2
y <- "sdsd"
z <- 2323322
a_list <- list("x" = x, "y" = y, "z" = z)

> a_list
$x
[1] 2

$y
[1] "sdsd"

$z
[1] 2323322
```

I want to write this list to a csv file, one row for each element. I tried `write.csv(a_list, file = "abc.csv")` and got this

```
    x   y       z
1   2   sdsd    2323322
```

If transpose the result, it would be what I want:

```
x, 2
y, sdsd
z, 2323322
```

Comment: This is a perfectly reasonable question, with sample code and what OP tried. I really see no reason to down-vote.

Comment: @Roman It might be a bit harsh, but I think the OP didn't do much research effort.

Comment: @Llopis of course one can always try harder, but ROI may quickly diminish if one is not very versed. I think minimal effort was shown and personally I'm satisfied up to the point where I'm ready to help out (posting answer now :) ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close, but you won't be off the hook that easy. I haven't checked the code, but I'm guessing that `write.table` coerces your list to a data.frame before pushing the contents to a file, as demonstrated here:

```
> as.data.frame(a_list)
  x    y       z
1 2 sdsd 2323322
```

This is fine, but you want it in reverse, where columns should be row names. You can use function `t()` for that.

```
> t(as.data.frame(a_list))
  [,1]     
x "2"      
y "sdsd"   
z "2323322"
```

This is now ready to be pushed to a `write.table`, which can be customized to do your bidding.

Here I explicitly turned row names on (it's already the default) and turned column names off. Quotes are not needed in this case so they're off as well.

```
write.table(t(as.data.frame(a_list)), 
            file = "myfile.txt", 
            row.names = TRUE, 
            col.names = FALSE,
            quote = FALSE)
```

Contents of `myfile.txt`:

```
x 2
y sdsd
z 2323322
```

If you are hell-bent on having commas after letters, you can do

```
out <- t(as.data.frame(a_list))
rownames(out) <- paste(rownames(out), ",", sep = "")

write.table(out, 
            file = "myfile.txt", 
            row.names = TRUE, 
            col.names = FALSE,
            quote = FALSE)

x, 2
y, sdsd
z, 2323322
```

Comment: @Belter if any of the answers solved your issue, consider checking the ckecmark below the score to mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

Here's my answer,

```
x <- 2
y <- "sdsd"
z <- 2323322
a_list <- list("x" = x, "y" = y, "z" = z)

write.csv(t(as.data.frame(a_list)), file= "abc.csv")
```

which I got from the following, https://stackoverflow.com/a/27594632/1945827 answer.

So, change list to data.frame, transpose and write to give,

```
    V1
x   2
y   sdsd
z   2323322
```

You may want to do something about the 'V1' column name.

Answer (score 2):

```
#Data
x <- 2
y <- "sdsd"
z <- 2323322
a_list <- list("x" = x, "y" = y, "z" = z)

#To show it works
rbind(a_list[1], a_list[2], a_list[3])
     x      
[1,] 2      
[2,] "sdsd" 
[3,] 2323322

#Save
write.csv(rbind(a_list[1], a_list[2], a_list[3]), "data.csv")
```

You can also add row names:

```
data<-rbind(a_list[1], a_list[2], a_list[3])
rownames(data)<-c("x,","y,","z,")
```

Or easier way round:

```
 write.csv(cbind(a_list), "data.csv")
```

Comment: I think `cbind(a_list)` without the indexing is a bit prettier and preserves list names.

Comment: There are quotes around values and row names don't appear to match desired output (missing comma).