# How in R can we split a table in multiple dataframes composed of the first column and each of the rest?

Tags: r, loops, merge, split

I have a dataframe in R of x columns where the first column (C1) contains species names and further column their abundances per samples. I would like to split that dataframe where each new splitted dataframe includes C1 + Cx. Therefore if there was 20 columns, there would be 19 dataframes with C1+C2, C1+C3,C1+C4, etc.

I have been able to split the different columns using lapply and split, but i can't find a way to attach to each of those splitted frames the column C1. Would any have suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way using `split.default` and `lapply`

```
# input data
iris2 <- iris[, c(5, 1:4)]
```

We split data column-wise excluding the first column, this returns a list.

```
iris2_split <- split.default(iris2[-1], names(iris2)[-1])
```

Then we use `lapply` and `cbind` to attach the first column of `iris2` the every entry in `iris2_split`.

```
out <- lapply(iris2_split, cbind, iris2[1])
```

Result (truncated)

```
lapply(out, head, 3)
#$Petal.Length
#  Petal.Length Species
#1          1.4  setosa
#2          1.4  setosa
#3          1.3  setosa

#$Petal.Width
#  Petal.Width Species
#1         0.2  setosa
#2         0.2  setosa
#3         0.2  setosa

#$Sepal.Length
#  Sepal.Length Species
#1          5.1  setosa
#2          4.9  setosa
#3          4.7  setosa

#$Sepal.Width
#  Sepal.Width Species
#1         3.5  setosa
#2         3.0  setosa
#3         3.2  setosa
```

Comment: Thanks! I managed furthermore to create multiple tables using list2env. My last struggle now is to export all these tables. Would you have a way to loop write all those created tables into txt files (One txt file per table)? Thanks again for your fast help!

Comment: Glad it worked. Check this post: [Export a list into a CSV or TXT file in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27594541/export-a-list-into-a-csv-or-txt-file-in-r)

Comment: Thanks again for your recommendation. I did try a similar way, however it saves under one file. Whereas I would need one txt file per table in the list. Is it just about removing the append = T?

Comment: Can you try something like `Map(f = write.csv, x = out, file = paste0("path/to/file/", names(out), ".csv")`

Comment: Hi I tried the method, however I get in the console a list of all samples with NULL under:                   Map(f = write.csv, x = out, file = paste0("file/path/", names(out), ".csv"))
$`GC1048d305cm`
NULL

$GC1070d57cm
NULL

$X1029d14to15cm
NULL

$X1029d1to3cm
NULL

$X1029d4to5cm
NULL

$X1029d8to10cm
NULL

Comment: Or if I use the example data I also end with same results:  Map(f = write.csv, x = out, file = paste0("path/file/", names(out), ".csv"))
$`Petal.Length`
NULL

$Petal.Width
NULL

$Sepal.Length
NULL

$Sepal.Width
NULL

Comment: Finally I used
for(i in seq_along(out)){
  write.table(out[[i]], file=paste0(filepath', names(out)[i], '.txt'),row.names = FALSE, quote=FALSE)
} And all worked. Thanks again!