# How to save an R list as csv or Excel file?

Tags: r, list, csv, output, export-to-excel

[R numerical list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GLvIi.png)

I wonder how to export the list above to csv or excel? I do not need to keep the data type, but having counts displayed next to Embase.n in a csv/Excel file would be very useful to me.
Many thanks for helping me out.

Comment: Have you tried converting it to data frame (`as.data.frame(list)`) and then use `write.csv`?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27594541/export-a-list-into-a-csv-or-txt-file-in-r) could help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I see, your list seems to consist of one single value for each element. You can use Jonathan V. Solórzano's way to get a very wide table. Alternatively you can use `unlist()` to collapse your list into a vector, and create a dataframe and export it.

```
mylist <- list(Embase.1 = 1, Embase.2 = 0, Embase.3 = 2)
v <- unlist(mylist)
df <- data.frame(Embase = v)
df
#         Embase
#Embase.1      1
#Embase.2      0
#Embase.3      2
write.csv(df, row.names = F)
```