# How to get a list of all unique elements by row in a table?

Tags: r

I need help with R in finding the right way to apply the same process as the `unique()` function does, just in the whole table. **My data are organized by rows**, with no column names. It is a big table, 130 X 180. So, what I would need is a list of all unique elements by row, and information on how many times each of the elements appears in each row.

example of my data:

```
Row1, F, M2, E, E, H, E, E, H, E, E, M, 21, E, M, L, L, L, L, L, E, H, L, L, L, L, L, L, L, L, L, L, E, H, L, L, L, L, L, L, L, L, L, E, H, L, L, L, L, L, L, L, L, L  
Row2, A3, A3, V, R, A3, A3, V, R, A3, A3, V, R, A3, A3, R, A3, A3, V, R, A3, A3, V, R, A3, A3, V, V, W, 12, N, N, N, W, N, N, N, 21, N, N, W, N, N, N, 21, N, N, W    
Row3, I, M, A1, A1, H, A1, A1, H, A1, A1, H, A1, A1, H, M, D2, M, L, L, L, L, D2, M, L, L, L, L, D2, M2, G, M2, G, M2, G, R, K, E, R, K, E, R, K, E, R, K, E  
Row4, H, A1, A1, H, A1, A1, H, A1, A1, M, A1, A1, H, A1, A1, A1, W, N, N, 21, N, N, W, N, 21, W, 21, W, W, Q, Q, Q, Q, Q, Q, L, F, D, Q, Q, Q, Q, Q, F, D, Q
```

Which can be found as a .txt file [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xrUNcyn0RWPFc39TIEu9j4rw4_I_oTln/view?usp=sharing)

The correct answer for `Row1` would be (plus the frequency of elements, which I don't know how to count):

```
> unique(Row1)
[1] " F"  " M2" " E"  " H"  " M"  " 21" " L"
```

But when I try to apply it to the whole table, it counts by columns, and I need the answer by rows.

Comment: I understand that you're frustrated with the closure of your previous question, but it's better practice to try to edit your previous question (and hope for re-opening) rather than post the same question again (if you must, it's polite to link to the previous attempt ...)

Comment: Hi Ben, sorry, I actually tried that, several times, but nothing seemed to change, the question stayed closed. So I was not totally  sure if that was a permanent state of it, excuse me, I am new to Stackflow, still need to learn how things work over here. Thank you for your patience and advices, and sorry for the extra trouble I gave you!

Comment: Fair enough. Maybe go back and delete the old question now ...

Comment: Fair enough! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `apply` to loop over the data and get the `unique`

```
apply(df1[-1], 1, unique)
```

If there are leading, lagging spaces, use `trimws` to remove those

```
apply(df1[-1], 1, function(x) unique(trimws(x)))
#[[1]]
#[1] "F"  "M2" "E"  "H"  "M"  "21" "L" 

#[[2]]
#[1] "A3" "V"  "R"  "W"  "12" "N"  "21" ""  

#[[3]]
# [1] "I"  "M"  "A1" "H"  "D2" "L"  "M2" "G"  "R"  "K"  "E"  ""  

#[[4]]
# [1] "H"  "A1" "M"  "W"  "N"  "21" "Q"  "L"  "F"  "D"  ""
```

If it needs the frequency, use `table`

```
apply(df1[-1], 1, table)
```

#### data

```
df1 <- read.csv("Data_exmpl.txt", fill = TRUE, header = FALSE)
```

Comment: Hi Akrun, thank you, this seems to work just fine! Can you please explain to me how you made unique() work by row and not by column? Thank you!

Comment: @DivnaDjokic it is the `MARGIN = 1` in `apply` that loop over row.  If you used `2`, it will loop over columns

Comment: Okay, that's great, thank you so much! Just one remark- I have a problem of exporting the results now, as it is a list of lists, which are pretty long (when working with the original data), so or it doesn't save everything, or there are numbers I do not understand. I tried all the answers given in this question <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27594541/export-a-list-into-a-csv-or-txt-file-in-r>. Do you happen to have any idea how to solve this?

Comment: @DivnaDjokic How do you want the output to be.  Should that be a single dataset or a `list` ?

Comment: @DivnaDjokic if you want to create a txt output with the list.  you can use `capture.output(out, 'file.txt')`

Comment: Thank you for the idea! It worked, with the slight modification `cat(capture.output(print(List), file="file.txt"))`
Thank you so much for your help, cheers!