# Exporting large lists in R as .txt or .csv

Tags: r

I have a question regarding this [Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27594541/export-a-list-into-a-csv-or-txt-file-in-r) particular problem, where the question is answered, but only partially.
Namely, getting the output using `cat(capture.output(print(my.list), file="test.txt"))` works for some elements of the list, but for longer ones does not give a full file, but rather it says  `[ reached getOption("max.print") -- omitted 299 entries ]` and so on.
Does anyone know of an alternative to exporting a list in R that does not have a limit in the no. of rows/columns?  I tried all of the offered solutions in the example from the link, non of the worked.
Important to mention is that I do not want to use `unlist` or `cbind`, because the groups within the list are important to stay the way they are.

Thanks!

Comment: It has been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27594541/export-a-list-into-a-csv-or-txt-file-in-r

Comment: this is the same link I posted as a part of my question, explaining the answers there didn't help me....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Divna, try this:

```
dat = list(a = 1:4, b = 1:8)
setwd("~/../Desktop/")
lapply(1:length(dat), function(x) write.table(t(as.data.frame(dat[x])), 
                                              'test.csv', append= T, sep=',', 
                                              quote = F, col.names = F))
```