# Getting rid of row numbers and quotes in R output

Tags: r, text, output

This is the output I have currently

```
[[1]]
[1] "chr2    11296660    11296700    AT2G2656011"

[[2]]
[1] "chr2    11249456    11249491    AT2G2644011"

[[3]]
[1] "chr2    9899738    9899756    AT2G2326010"

[[4]]
[1] "chr1    25428966    25428999    AT1G6781014"

[[5]]
[1] "chr4    8880515    8880553    AT4G155505"

[[6]]
[1] "chr4    9739572    9739608    AT4G174605"
```

I wish to remove the quotes and row numbers with the brackets around them and simply have something to this effect

```
chr2    11296660    11296700    AT2G2656011
chr2    11249456    11249491    AT2G2644011
```

how would I go about it? When I use unlist for some reason it combines rows together into a single line.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R: Print list to a text file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3044794/r-print-list-to-a-text-file) ... for future reference, please spend a few minutes searching SO and Google before posting.

Comment: You want just to print to STDOUT? E.g. something like `write(do.call(rbind, l), "")`? Or you want to convert to a `data.frame`, e.g. `read.table(text = do.call(rbind, l))`?

Comment: Wouldn't this just be `lapply( yourlist, cat, file = "myfile.txt", append=TRUE)`

Comment: Or even more fun to the console `invisible(lapply(x, cat, "\n"))`