# how to write data of principal component analysis of protein in R

Tags: r, extract, pca

i am very new with R i want to write data of pca but i found an error which is given below how can i resolve this problem kindly help me.

```
pc <- pca.xyz(xyz[,ca.inds$xyz])
write.table(pc, file="pc.txt", sep="\t")
Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE, stringsAsFactors   =  stringsAsFactors) : 
cannot coerce class ""pca"" to a data.frame
```

Answer (score 1):

`write.table` requires a matrix or a data frame. However `pca.xyz` returns a list. Check the `Value` paragraph [here](http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/R/library/bio3d/html/pca.xyz.html) to see the components it contains. If you want to save the components of a list to a file check [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3044794/r-print-list-to-a-text-file)